# Remove Rows in JIDE - Group Table

Tags: java, jide

I’m using `jidesoft.grid.DefaultGroupTableModel` class wrapping  `swing.table.DefaultTableModel` .

Problem is When I’m trying to remove a  grouped row  (DefaultGroupRow )  using the  method
`jidesoft.grid.DefaultGroupTableModel.removeRow(row index)`  ,

The Row is removed visually only  , and  still exists  in the  `swing.table.DefaultTableModel`.

When i preform the `groupAndRefresh` method,  the deleted row is re-created in the front end.

How can I remove the grouped table row that will be removed from the swing `DefaultTableModel`.

Thanks in advance.

Uri W.

Answer (score 0):

GroupTableModel is just a grouped view into the original table model which in your case a DefaultTableModel. GroupTableModel will never modify the original table model. If you would like to remove the row from the DefaultTableModel, you will have to use DefaultTableModel#removeRow method.