# What is the correct way to remove a row from an underlying DefaultTableModel when using JIDE GroupTable?

Tags: java, matlab, jide

I have a JIDE GroupTable placed in a JideScollablePane inside a JideTabbedPane, instantiated from inside Matlab running on the EDT (via javaObjectEDT).

I am catching an event from a JButton and deleting the selected row. If I use the GroupTable.getModel.removeRow method the underlying DefaultTableModel does not remove the row.

If I remove the row from the DefaultTableModel directly the JideTabbedPane containing the GroupTable becomes unresponsive.

I am able to "work around" this as I am actually synching another underlying Matlab business object with the GroupTable view so the GroupTable.removeRow is sufficient, however this doesn't feel like the right way to do this... and if I call groupAndRefresh on the GroupTable the underlying DefaultTableModel reappears. (see [Remove Rows in JIDE - Group Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163420/remove-rows-in-jide-group-table))

Which removeRow method should I really be using?